# How to make a an image with 1 pixel height the background-image of a div?

Tags: css, background-image, pixel

I have an image which is 1 pixel high and 600 pixels long, however when I set this image to be the background of a div, the image is not displayed. For example:

```
<div style="background-image:url(.images/goldSplitterMed.png); background-repeat:repeat-y"></div>
```

The repeat I think is irrelevant but I've just used it incase.

I've tried setting the width and heights but also to no prevail.

Is there anything else that could be stopping this image appear?

Thanks

Comment: `background-repeat` is unnecessary when used with a `background-image`. CSS background images repeat automatically.

Comment: Are you sure the path to the image is correct? If so add height:1px; to that style attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is right now, your `<div>` has zero height because it has no content. Background images are not content ;)

Either put something in there, or add a `height` to the CSS.

Comment: Two problems, the path was wrong also (Missing a "/", but it was correct earlier I believe and it wasn't working with height of 1 pixel.                                                                I've set the height to 10 and put content in it...and the background image works. However without content and height set to 1 pixel - no image is displayed.

Comment: Going to use an image to display it instead of a div, think this will be easier.

Thought page layout would be tidier with a div representing the image, but I guess there is no harm in it.

Thanks for comments everyone.